# Why is DocType null after transformation?

Tags: java, xml, doctype

I receive a document `finalDocument` and want to set the same `DocType` as the input document `xmlDocument`. This is how I do it:

```
finalDocument = icBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes("UTF-8"))));

Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

DocumentType doctype = xmlDocument.getDoctype();

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, doctype.getSystemId());
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC, doctype.getPublicId());    

transformer.transform(new DOMSource(finalDocument), new StreamResult(writer));
```

However, for some reason the `DocType` of `finalDocument` is not set. I don't get an exception or anything - it's just `null`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Btw: `doctype.getSystemId()` and `doctype.getPublicId()` are not null and valid.

Comment: Well, does it have a DocType to start with? It's never updated in the code fragment you show.

Comment: @forty-two Do you mean `finalDocument`? Does it matter if it has one?

Comment: How is the w3c tag relevant? This doesn't exactly seem to be a question about the standard itself, rather a programming problem.

Comment: @tambre Right. But then how is the xml tag relevant because this is just a problem I have with a Java library. All that would remain is the java tag but this question is not about Java. But it's a question about a Java object that happens to represent an XML object which gets imported under `org.w3c.*`. At least that's how I'd justify the tag.

Comment: I think tagging with XML makes sense, as you're trying to do something associated with XML. If you were to create a question, would you tag it with the library creator's name? Probably not, instead you'd likely use the library's name. Also tag wiki leans to be more about standard definitions, but it's unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `finalDocument` variable is passed as a source to the `transform` method:

```
void javax.xml.transform.Transformer.transform(Source xmlSource, Result outputTarget) throws TransformerException
```

The result of the transformation is placed in the second parameter. So I would expect that the docType's you have set with the `setOutputProperty` will be placed on the target, which is your writer object.

Comment: True - that's why you shouldn't copy & paste code from other. ^^